# How to obtain a constant expression when std::is_constant_evaluated?

Tags: c++, c++20

Let's start with the example ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/erW6fr)):

```
constexpr int len(int v) {
    if (std::is_constant_evaluated()) {
        // static_assert(v > 0); // ERR: 'v' is not a constant expression
        return v;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

using A = std::array<int, len(3)>;
```

The problem is, that the `static_assert` won't compile (gcc / clang latest 10.x releases). Apparently, `v` isn't realized to be `constexpr` when `std::is_constant_evaluated` returns `true`. But clearly, by the use of `len`, it actually is.

**Question**: Is it possible to use a variable as `constexpr` if and only if `std::is_constant_evaluated`? If so, how?

Comment: No, arguments to a function are never constant expressions (even if the function is being constant evaluated), so you can't do this. You'll have to pass `v` in as a template parameter or something like that.

Comment: I believe the `if` needs to be a consexpr `if` for it to work.

Comment: @ALX23z No that's definitely wrong. If it's an `if constexpr` then `std::is_constant_evaluated` is tautologically true.

Comment: @cigien right... but this is inherently troublesome as now it is now a "non-constexpr if". And it creates limitations to written code. Guess `constexpr` programming is still far off from being done.

Comment: @ALX23z I'm not sure what limitations you're thinking of. These comments will get removed, so perhaps you could post a question about your confusion.

Comment: @cigien I don't think about anything concrete right now. The intention of constexpr if is to split compilation into two routes. I'd expect that when checking whether your current scope is constexpr evaluated or not would result in compilation split as well. However, no it is impossible currently - both routes need to be compiled for both cases. And this is profoundly wrong. The function is like an easy-to-implement patch for today instead of a true solution.

Comment: @ALX23z Of course both routes need to be compiled for both cases. What is the functionality you're missing by this being true? What people usually want is to have function parameters usable as constant expressions -- but only compiling one side of the branch or the other wouldn't give you that anyway.

Comment: @Barry I guess that's is the functionality I wanted. Being able to compile only one side is indeed insufficient as you pointed out but it is a necessary part. This goes back to the argument that we still lack constexpr programming features...

Comment: @ALX23z That doesn't answer the question. _Why_ is that the functionality you wanted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Apparently, `v` isn't realized to be `constexpr` when `std::is_constant_evaluated` returns `true`. But clearly, by the use of `len`, it actually is.

No, it's actually not.

Function parameters are not constant expressions. It doesn't matter if you're in the middle of constant evaluation or not. You cannot use `v` as a constant expression in any context. `static_assert` requires a constant expression - this is why you cannot use `v`.

> Question: Is it possible to use a variable as constexpr if and only if `std::is_constant_evaluated`? If so, how?

No, it is not. Because in order to use a variable as a constant expression, well, that's a template. And `is_constant_evaluated` can't conditionally make your function into a function template, that's just not how the compilation process can work. See [P0992](https://wg21.link/p0992).

Answer (score 2):

Not possible, but also unnecessary.

Instead of using a `static_assert`, you can `throw` something. Since you're in a `constexpr` context, it will give you a compile-time error.

Comment: Oh, nice [workaround](https://godbolt.org/z/jqechG) for `static_assert` :)

Comment: Could you elaborate, why it's not possible / allowed?

Comment: @m8mble No idea, but that's how things work. At least now.

Comment: All those workaround about the language weakness make me think about those program developed by mechanical engineers that use Visual Basic within Excel to code simulations!

Comment: This looks like a hack - it even generates a strange error message. I wonder (if static_assert does not work here), why there is no construct like 'constexpr_assert (condition, message), which prints a nice compiler error message, if the condition is not met and the call is evaluated at compile time (the same way, static_assert works)'